# How to post parameter from body [FromBody] and retrieve objects in a <list> in WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How to post parameter to a body and get the object in a list? IO am able to retrieve the data using this post method in my controller with parameter appended to the URI

Accounts controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("mini")]
public List<MiniStatement> GetMiniStatement(string accountNumber)
{
    var miniState = BusinessLayer.Api.AccountHolderApi.GetMiniStatement(accountNumber);
    return miniState.ToList();
}
```

But how do I pass the parameter `[FromBody]` and retrieve the data in a list?

MiniStatement class:

```
public  class MiniStatement
{
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string TranDate { get; set; }
    public string Trans { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

`GetMiniStatement` method in DB layer:

```
public static List<MiniStatement> GetMiniStatement(string accountNumber)
{
    List<MiniStatement> resultList = new List<MiniStatement>();

    using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;UserId = postgres; " + "Password = pes; Database = pmc;"))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sms.dep_mini_statement(@AccountNumber);", conn))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNumber", accountNumber);

            using (var dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    var result = new MiniStatement
                    {
                        AccountNumber = accountNumber,
                        TranDate = (string)dr[0],
                        Trans = (string)dr[1],
                        Amount = (decimal)dr[2]
                    };
                    resultList.Add(result);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return resultList;    
}
```

And the **Route**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("MobileBankingApi", "v1/{controller}/{action}");
```

Comment: If you want to send body requests, the easiest way is create an object in your api layer with all the properties you want. then you can accept it in your method. When you pass the object in JSON format to your webapi method, you will actually get the populated object. So you can do whatever logic you want with the object.

Comment: How do i get the object in <list> sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you posting data as json you could populate the AccountNumber in an object as this

```
{ "AccountNumber": "23" }
```

Then add the [FromBody] in the controller method as this

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("mini")]
public List<MiniStatement> GetMiniStatement([FromBody] MiniStatement state)
{
    var miniState = BusinessLayer.Api.AccountHolderApi.GetMiniStatement(state.AccountNumber);
    return miniState;
}
```

Also, as the BusinessLayer.Api.AccountHolderApi.GetMiniStatement() returns a list you can just pass the response as is

Comment: hello sir..i need to pass the param accountNumber to body not the URI.Getting 404 when passing the response as is with return ministate.

Comment: Thank you sir.worked like a charm and learned a new thing.Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you can do the below.

Create a model class in your api.

```
public class Account
{
 string AccountNumber{get;set;}
}
```

Then take it in your webapi method.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("mini")]
public IActionResult GetMiniStatement([FromBody]Account account)
{
    var miniState = BusinessLayer.Api.AccountHolderApi.GetMiniStatement(account.AccountNumber);
    return new ObjectResult(miniState.ToList());
}
```

your request body should look like this.

```
{
 "AccountNumber":"someNUmber"
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: sir, i think asp.net-core uses IActionResult while asp.net-web-api2 uses IHttpActionResult.i did tried this and like you said tried to return  return new ObjectResult(miniState.ToList());Now i am getting this error--Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'ObjectResult',Cannot access protected internal constructor 'ObjectResult' here

Comment: @OLDMONK Please refer to the below link. It will explain the web api 2 return types.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and the link sir.Thank for your time.